# Html.ActionLink bypass encoding for route values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I am trying to bypass the route value encoding that Html.ActionLink does, when processed on Server. For example I Have following ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "_SoftwareRequestEdit", "SoftwareRequest", new {id = "#= Id #"}, null)
```

and it generates a link like this

```
<a href="/Admin/SoftwareRequest/_SoftwareRequestEdit/%23%3d%20Id%20%23">Edit</a>
```

but I wan't to send this to the browser instead

```
<a href="/Admin/SoftwareRequest/_SoftwareRequestEdit/#= Id #">Edit</a>
```

The **"#= Id #"** route value has to be sent to the browser as it is, because it is processed by a front end framework Kendo UI Web, which replaces the expression **"#= Id #"** by a corresponding integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite messy... However, if you need to do it, you could always build the tag manually.

```
<a href="@(Url.Action("Edit", "_SoftwareRequestEdit", "SoftwareRequest"))/#= ID #">Edit</a>
```

Please note, I have not tested this code...

Edit:
It may in fact give you what you need, because most browsers will url encode whatever is in the "a" tag anyway as spaces are not a valid url character: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: What if I wan't to use more than one route values (link parameters) ?

Comment: For this case, where I have to pass only one parameter, your solution works. So, I will close this question with your suggested answer.

Answer (score 0):

Html.ActionLine has an overload with fragment param

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, string protocol, string hostName, string fragment, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
```

protocol and hostname can just pass empty string

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand your response. I tried using the overload that you suggested passing empty strings to host and protocol, but MVC still sends encoded link to the browser, as in my question.

Comment: routeValues={},fragment="= Id #"

Comment: I preferred the @FamiliarPie approach.